# SQL Image field divided by 2

Tags: sql

Could anyone help me on the below please?

I have a field called F1.Images and I need to divide by 2 ONLY when my other field W1.Plex is Duplex else I need to retain the F1.Images count.

Thanks Satya

Comment: What have you tried so far? What database engine is this? Have you looked at your RDMS's case logic (`Case`/`When`)?

Comment: please think of yourself as the person who will try to answer the question.Currently question needs more info.Look here on ways to improve  question :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I have figured it out, here is the answer:

Case 
    WHEN W1.Plex = 'Duplex' then (F1.images / 2) 
                            Else F1.images 
End AS Pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted Brad.

Used `Case/When` logic. Here's the Answer:

```
Case 
    WHEN W1.Plex = 'Duplex' then (F1.images / 2) 
                            Else F1.images 
End AS Pages
```